# Creating Mulitple If statment for Converting height

Tags: java, if-statement

```
  public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
  {
    int leftOver = heightInInches % IN_PER_FOOT;

    if(heightInInches < (IN_PER_FOOT * 2)){
        return "1 foot " + leftOver + " inches";
    }
    else{ return "";
    }

    if(heightInInches < (IN_PER_FOOT * 3) && heightInInches > (heightInInches * 2)){
        return "2 foot " + leftOver + " inches";
    }
    else{
        return "";
}
```

I want to make it return "1 foot 4 inches" or however tall they are..
I got the first if statment to work but what would i do to continue up to like 6 feet.. I tried just adding another one but im pretty sure thats not how to do it. How can i put this together?

Comment: well, the second if-else statements would never get called. since both in the if and in the else you return.. since i'm using the metric, i don't know how to do the conversion, but you should check this out first

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler just to calculate the foot as well?

```
public String convertHeightToFeetInches()
{
    int inches = heightInInches % IN_PER_FOOT;
    int foot = heightInInches / IN_PER_FOOT;
    return "" + foot + " foot and " + inches + " inches";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a division statement to come up with the number if feet in 'heightInInches'.

Can you try that?

For example, I'm confident that if I know someone is 50 inches tall, I can quickly calculate that the person is at least 4 feet tall.

Once you have that working, we'll work on the inches.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the logic correct as it is, but you do need a little push.  Consider a height between 1 and 2 feet.  In mathematical terms, we would describe this as 1 < x <= 2.  Consider now what that would translate to in Java - what about x must be true?  Hint:  it's two conditions.

Next, an if-else if-else won't work if you have an `else` just sitting there.  `else` will execute if nothing else matches with it (and that will occur often).  Place an `if` after those `else`s.